# On Ubuntu 19.10's guest virtual machine, the login screen does no longer show up after installing VirtualBox Guest Additions, on host Arch Linux

Tags: virtualbox, login, guest-additions

#### Specs

- **Guest:** Ubuntu 19.10;
- **Host:** Arch Linux;
- VirtualBox 6.0.14;
- On host Arch Linux, I have `virtualbox-host-modules-arch` installed.

```
| DE        | KDE Plasma 5.17.0                 |
| CPU       | AMD Ryzen 7 2700X (16) @ 3.700GHz |
| GPU       | NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660           |
| RAM       | 16GB DDR4                         |
| Kernel    | 5.3.7-arch1-1-ARCH x86_64         |
```

#### Steps

Based on [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm#22745):

1. I installed the packages `build-esstential`, `dkms` and `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`;
2. I rebooted;
3. I ran the ISO from `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`;
4. I rebooted;
5. The login screen does no longer show up.

For the login screen to show up, I have to enter into chroot from Live USB for uninstalling all VirtualBox Guest Additions packages. I did once. But I depend on VirtualBox Guest Addition for sharing the host's folders.

#### Observations

- I also disabled 3D acceleration, but the login screen also does not show up.
- I use PIIX3 chipset, USB Tablet pointing device, and VBoxSVGA graphics controller (I switched from to VBoxVGA, but the login screen does not show up).

#### Question

How to fix the login screen which does no longer show up after having installed VirtualBox Guest Addition on Ubuntu's guest virtual machine?

#### Update 2

Observe that I could not enter into the TTY. I entered via chroot from Live USB and removed the Guest Additions, the login screen showed up, but as I depend on Guest Additions for sharing the host's folders, I need to fix the login screen.

Comment: here exactly the same. I think it is the video driver has some problem. I will try to blacklist the vbox video driver

Comment: I try to add vboxvideo into modprobe blacklist. But  it does not work. It always load the vboxvideo. drm will somehow depends on it. clipboard sharing actually only need vboxsf and vboxguest I think.

Comment: there is no need to use chroot. Just press e in grub and add nomodeset. Then host+F3 will give you console and let you remove the vbox drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue after updating and installing Guest Additions.  Found that if I set the VM to VMSVGA, the login screen shows up and everything seems normal.

Comment: I also switched to VMSVGA, but the log screen did not show up.

Comment: For my it solved by changing it to VboxSVGA.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me as well. I found that at the Ubuntu login screen, I had to manually click and drag the edge of the VirtualBox window to make it small (smaller than 1600 x 900 pixels, in fact), and then the login screen displayed AND the mouse registered my clicks (to click on my name, etc.).

In the View menu, I keep the "Auto-Resize Guest Display" option checked, so that after I log in I can maximize the VirtualBox window and it will automatically increase the resolution.

This trick worked regardless of the Graphics Controller selected. Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Increasing Video Memory in Display settings did work to me with this issue